# Best way to handle Date Ordering to reach better performance?

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework

I have large tables, contains DateTime columns to store exact time of some events and actions in my application. In some cases, users can enter the date of an event.

I want to validate event sequences, find events by the time of happening, and such things.

If I order events by DateTime, it's time consuming in large data. If I order by Id, there's no guaranty that users data entry is ordered, also users are not responsible to determine the sequence (they just enter date time). I prefer to order by a numeric field instead of DateTime.

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that a datetime will be stored as an integer number of ticks since a fixed point in time (generally Jan. 1st 1970).  To compare datetimes it is just an integer comparison of this single value, it doesn't need to compare year, month, day, etc. That is unless you're storing the date as a string, and not as a datetime.

My guess is that your database is internally storing the data sorted by ID, and that the ID is also indexed, which is why that's so quick.  Your problem isn't sorting on a datatime, it's simply sorting on a non-ID column.  As Reed suggested, you probably just need to index the column.  It's also possible that you're doing something, somewhere, in a way that you shouldn't.  It's hard to say what that might be without seeing the code, the DB configuration, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Ordering by DateTime columns should not be slow, even on large data, provided your database has that column indexed.

I would, personally, do the ordering directly on the `DateTime` (with an index on the db), but make sure that your LINQ queries limit the results to the appropriate date window.

Comment: You mean isn't there no big difference between order by indexed date time and bigint over 14,000,000 records?

Comment: @Reza No - a DateTime, when stored in the DB, is really a number.  If you index it, it's going to be a similar speed in the query to other checks....